# How does one compute this heavy integral?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

The integral is $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma\frac{\exp(z^2-\cos(iz)-4)}{z-2}dz$$
where $\Gamma$ is the unit circle.

Here's how I tried to parametrize it:

$z=e^{i\theta}$ on $\theta\in [0, 2\pi]$, so the integral becomes
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\frac{\exp(e^{2i\theta}-\cosh(e^{i\theta})-4)}{e^{i\theta}-2}(e^{i\theta})dz=\frac{e^4}{\pi i}\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{u^2}}{(u-2)e^{e^{-u}+e^u}}du$$ where $u=e^{u\theta}$ and $du=ie^{u\theta}d\theta$.

Have no idea what to do next. There must be some kind of a trick that I don't know. Would appreciate some hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integrand is analytic within the contour. Thus the integral along the closed contour is zero.